# Safari audio HTML5 issue

Tags: ios, networking, safari, html5-audio

I'm working on an iOS/MacOS issue.

I'm trying to play a simple audio file through a HTML5 audio element, and everything is working as expected except on iOS/MacOS.

My app is built on Symfony, using Nginx and custom PHP controllers to serve the audio resource. The audio element's given source is a link to a route that handles the streaming.

My logical is the following :

- Get the file from url ID
- Read request headers to find expected range and length
- Setting up the good headers to force 206 Partial Content behaviour
- Writing expected file chunks and returning a 206 response.

Here is the code for this:

```
public function getAudio(Request $request, $audioId)
    {
            /*
             * Getting the file
             */
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $voice = $em->getRepository("CoreBundle:Audio")->findOneById($audioId);
            $media = $audio->getFile();
            $path = $this->container->get('sonata.media.twig.extension')->path($media, 'reference');
            $file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../web$path";

            /*
             * Setting length and offset for serving the right chunk
             */
            $offset = 0;
            $requestedRange = $request->headers->get("Range");
            $size = $media->getSize();
            $length = $size;

            if($requestedRange){
                preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $requestedRange, $matches);
                $offset = intval($matches[1]);
                if(count($matches) > 2){
                    $length = intval($matches[2]) - $offset + 1;
                }
                else{
                    $length = ($size) - $offset;
                }
            }

            if(file_exists($file) && $length) {
                $file = fopen($file, 'r');
                fseek($file, $offset);
                $data = fread($file, $length);
                fclose($file);

                if($requestedRange){
                header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $offset . '-' . ($offset + $length-1) . '/' . $size);
                }
                else{
                    header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.($size-1).'/'.$size);
                }
                
                /*
                 * Forcing some headers in the response to fit request attempts
                 */
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Expires: 0");
                header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline');
                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                header('Content-Length: '.$length);
                header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


                print($data);

                return new Response("",206);
      }
            else{
                return new Response("",200);
            }
        }
```

Again, everything is working fine on Firefox and Chrome, file is streamed and played perfectly.
But when it comes to IOS and MacOS, the file just doesn't play. A peek at network console shows two subsequent requests, with the last one in error (see next links).

However, no error is logged in PHP and I'm now completely stuck.

[first-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcS2i.png)

[second-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ukrt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The logical was fine but the management of the response wasn't.

After reading the Symfony documentation about `Response`, I just changed every `header()` function to:

```
$response->setHeaders()
```

And every `print($data)` to:

```
$response = new Response($data);
```

Returning the complete `Response` object did the job.